# How can Swagger show both put and get versions of the same Azure function?

Tags: azure-functions, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have an Azure function (V3) with the following declaration

```
[Function("GetCases")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> GetCases([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.User, "put", "get", Route = "Case/{page}/{pageSize}/{sort}/{filter?}")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext executionContext, int page, int pageSize, string sort, string filter)
        {
            var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("GetCourtCases");
            logger.LogInformation("GetCourtCases function processed a request.");

            return await g.GetMany(req, page, pageSize, sort, filter);
        }
```

To return a paged dataset with a sort string and optional filter.  That is the GET operation.  Using a PUT, I can send a JSON object which contains lists of values and the columns these values should be searched for on.

So basically I have the same function that can be called with either GET or PUT, where PUT adds information, as seen in the console:
[image]

Problem is, using OpenAPI v0.9 (the latest preview), swagger will only only show one of the configurations, depending on which is specified first in the function heading.

I could explain this in the Description, but is there a way to tell swagger this is both a PUT and a GET operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no, there is no way to tell Swagger this one Function is both a `GET` and a `PUT` operation.

For details, see [Justin Yoo's comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/issues/68#issuecomment-797855500) on the GitHub issue [Doesn't support multiple operations (for example, GET, POST) for one endpoint](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/issues/68).

> That's correct. Although technically one Function method can take more than one HTTP verb/method, semantically it should be two different operations.
>
> Therefore, I would recommend separating multiple verbs/methods from each other, and giving them respective operation IDs.